# Change small icon in push notification on Android with Delphi XE 10.3 Rio

Tags: android, delphi, push-notification, firemonkey

I have a problem with the small icon in push notification on Android devices.
The icon shows black.

I have followed the steps indicated by pudnivec74 in this post [How to change small icon image in notification on Android device with DELPHI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678344/how-to-change-small-icon-image-in-notification-on-android-device-with-delphi) , and it works, but only when application is running, when the application is closed the icon stills appears black.

I have also added in the file AndroidManifest.template.xml these lines:

`<meta-data android: name = "com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android: resource = "@ drawable / ic_notification" />`

and remains the same.

Does anyone know the solution?

Here is the code that I used:

```
    procedure TFrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
       try
        {$IF DEFINED(ANDROID)}
        APushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.GCM);
        APushService.AppProps[TPushService.TAppPropNames.GCMAppID] :=UResource.NUMEROPROYECTOANDROID;
        {$ELSE}
        APushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.APS);
        {$ENDIF}

        AServiceConnection := TPushServiceConnection.Create(APushService);
        AServiceConnection.Active := True;

        {$IF DEFINED(ANDROID)}
          AServiceConnection.OnReceiveNotification := OnReceiveNotificationPushAndroid;
        {$ELSE}
          AServiceConnection.OnReceiveNotification := OnReceiveNotificationPushiOS;
        {$ENDIF}

        VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.Always;
      except on E: Exception do
      end;
     end;


     procedure TFrmMain.OnReceiveNotificationPushAndroid(Sender: TObject;
      const ANotification: TPushServiceNotification);
    var
      {$IFDEF ANDROID}
      Ntf: JNotification;
      ntfBuilder: JNotificationCompat_Builder;
      ntfManager: JNotificationManager;
      {$ENDIF}
      Mensaje, Titulo: String;
    begin
      {$IFDEF ANDROID}
      try
        //ShowMessage(ANotification.Json.ToString);
        Titulo := Copy(ANotification.Json.GetValue('title').ToString, 2, Length(ANotification.Json.GetValue('title').ToString)-2);
        Mensaje := Copy(ANotification.Json.GetValue('message').ToString, 2, Length(ANotification.Json.GetValue('message').ToString)-2);

        ntfBuilder:= TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(TAndroidHelper.Context);
        ntfBuilder.setSmallIcon(TAndroidHelper.Context.getResources.getIdentifier(StringToJString('ic_notification'), StringToJString('drawable'), TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName));
        ntfBuilder.setContentTitle(StrToJCharSequence(Titulo));
        ntfBuilder.setContentText(StrToJCharSequence(Mensaje));

        ntfBuilder.setAutoCancel(True);

        Ntf:= ntfBuilder.build;
        Ntf.defaults := TJNotification.JavaClass.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        if Ntf.defaults <> TJNotification.JavaClass.DEFAULT_VIBRATE then
          Ntf.defaults := Ntf.defaults + TJNotification.JavaClass.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


        ntfManager:= TJNotificationManager.Wrap((TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
        ntfManager.notify(1, Ntf);
      except on E: Exception do
      end;


      {$ENDIF}
    end;
```